# How to get the timezone offset in GMT(Like GMT+7:00) from iOS device using codename?

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to get timezone from iOS device by using following code:

DateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("z",Locale.getDefault());
String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime);

But it always return me in format of zone and city ex: Asia/Kolkata, whereas I want it to be like GMT+4-30.

On Android device and simulator it works fine but on iOS device it goes with city name.
So how do I get only timezone like GMT+ or GMT- for iOS?

Any information would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using `DateUtil.getOffset()` e.g.:

```
int offset = new DateUtil().getOffset(timeInMS);
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I checked in documentation the DateUtil class is in com.codenameone1.ui.util package, but when I try to use it in code, the DateUtil doesn't exist.

Comment: Make sure you're using the current version of the libraries